# looping grep function

Tags: bash

So I was building a script for a co-worker so she can easily scan files for occurrences of strings. But I am having trouble with my grep command.

```
    #!/bin/bash -x

filepath() {
echo -n "Please enter the path of the folder you would like to scan, then press [ENTER]: "
read path
filepath=$path
}

filename () {
echo -n "Please enter the path/filename you would like the output saved to, then press [ENTER]: "
read outputfile
fileoutput=$outputfile
touch $outputfile
}
searchstring () {
echo -n "Please enter the string you would like to seach for, then press [ENTER]: "
read searchstring
string=$searchstring
}
codeblock() {
for i in $(ls "${filepath}")
do
  grep "'${string}'" "$i" | wc -l | sed "s/$/ occurance(s) in "${i}" /g" >> "${fileoutput}"
done
}

filepath
filename
searchstring
codeblock
exit
```

I know there are a lot of extra variable "redirects" Just practicing my scripting. Here is the error I am receiving when I run the command.

```
+ for i in '$(ls "${filepath}")'
+ grep ''\''<OutageType>'\''' *filename*.DONE.xml
+ wc -l
+ sed 's/$/ occurance(s) in *filename*.DONE.xml /g'
grep: *filename*.DONE.xml: No such file or directory
```

However if I run the grep command with the wc and sed functions from CLI it works fine.

```
# grep '<OutageNumber>' "*filename*.DONE.xml" | wc -l | sed "s/$/ occurance(s) in "*filename*.DONE.xml" /g"
13766 occurance(s) in *filename*.DONE.xml
```

Comment: why dont you use recursive function of grep?

Comment: She was, but it seems like the loop was completing the scans quicker than just grepping the whole folder recursively.

Comment: whole folder but specific filetypes? how did you/she measure it?

Comment: the whole folder is the same file type (basically .xml logs). I had a working command for like 5 minutes but forgot to take a .bak and now I am stuck troubleshooting because I added the input functions so she can use it on more than just this one scan if she needs to. The script ran for like 3-4 minutes at most, and she had been scanning for like 10-15 at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going wrong here.

> ```
> for i in $(ls "${filepath}")
> ```

The value of filepath is `*filename*.DONE.xml`, and if you assume that the `*` get expanded there, that won't happen. A double-quoted string variable is taken literally by the shell, the `*` will not get expanded.

If you want wildcard characters to be expanded to match filename patterns,
then you cannot double-quote the variable in the command.

Next, it's strongly discouraged to parse the output of the `ls` command. This would be better:

```
for i in ${filepath}
```

And this still won't be "perfect', because if there are no files matching the pattern,
then `grep` will fail. To avoid that, you could enable the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in ${filepath}
```

Finally, I suggest to eliminate this for loop,
and use the `grep` command directly:

```
grep "'${string}'" ${filepath} | ...
```

Comment: `filepath` is being used as a function as well as a variable in the given script by OP. Is that allowable/valid?

Comment: @User123 that's a horrible idea, but valid, it works in Bash :-/

Comment: Ohk, Thanks..would be careful :)

Comment: the *filename* were just edits by me so the actual filenames were not displayed.